# If you have hash of hashes how to remove the values of first hash - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

What is the simplest way from:

```
{"Wednesday"=>{"Horse"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}, 
"Thursday"=>{"Horse"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}}
```

to this?

```
{"Wednesday"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}, 
"Thursday"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}
```

I've been struggling in my console for 2 hours now.

Would appreciate any answers!

p.s. the Horse is a variable like: FrenchStalion, BelgianStalion, Lipicanec ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **functional** style solution (without modifying the original hash or using extra variables - a solution that looks elegant for me)

```
hash.reduce({}) { |acc, (k, v)| acc.merge(Hash[k, *v.values]) }
# => {"Wednesday"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}, "Thursday"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}
```

Comment: I would never claim an answer I propose is "elegant". Surely, elegance, like beauty, is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree up to a point... It could be a long discussion, so I've rephrased my sentence.

Answer (score 2):

How about this.

```
hash = {"Wednesday"=>{"Horse"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}, 
"Thursday"=>{"Horse"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}}
a ={}
hash.each do |k,v|
  a[k]=v.values.first
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
  a = {"Wednesday"=>{"Horse"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}, 
       "Thursday"=>{"Horse"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}}
  d = {} 
  a.each { |k,v| d[k] = v["Horse"]  }
  puts d
```

Comment: Horse is a variable. I updated my question. And thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do

```
hash = {"Wednesday"=>{"Horse"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}, 
"Thursday"=>{"Horse"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}}

hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = v['Horse']}
# => {"Wednesday"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}, "Thursday"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}
```

**update**

```
hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = v.shift.last}
# => {"Wednesday"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}, "Thursday"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}
```

Comment: Horse is a variable. I updated my question. And thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Hash[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) method comes in handy for constructing hashes:

```
hash = {
  "Wednesday"=>{"Horse"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}},
  "Thursday"=>{"Horse"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}
}

x = "Horse"

Hash[
  hash.collect do |k, v|
    [ k, v[x] ]
  end
]

# => {"Wednesday"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}, "Thursday"=>{"9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the form of [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged:

```
h = { "Wednesday"=>{ "Horse"=>{ "9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1 } }, 
      "Thursday" =>{ "Horse"=>{ "9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1 } } }

key = "Horse"

h.merge(h) { |*_,g| g[key] }
  #=> { "Wednesday"=>{ "9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1 },
  #     "Thursday" =>{ "9.0"=>1, "10.0"=>1 } }
```